# Objective C: How do I substring an email address in text field to firstpart separated by @

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have been scratching my head trying to find any resources on substringing an email address I get from a textfield into getting the first part before the @ symbol. Ive tried looking at the documentation, playing around with the componentsseparatedbyString.

No luck.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSString* email = @"foo@bar.com";
NSString* username = [[email componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

You'll want to do some error checking most likely, but that's the meat of it.

Comment: Thanks, I sort of had objectAtIndex a separate entry pointing to that and it didnt work, but thanks mate, this works

Answer (score 4):

[Using regular expressions](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/):

```
NSString * email = @"foo@bar.com";
NSString * name = [email stringByMatching:@"^([^@]+)@" capture:1];
```

Comment: Why include a 3rd party library if you don't have to?

Comment: @nall I prefer using RegexKitLite, which just requires linking in the icu library and #importing some NSString categories

Comment: @Dave I agree -- RegexKitLite is great, but it's still extra code that you have to maintain/update.

Comment: @nall +1 good point. I keep things like RKL checked out from SVN to a directory, then just reference the files in my projects.  Every now and then I run a script the updates all my checked out projects, and then all my projects that use RKL (or whatever) get automatically updated.  Ditto on my private frameworks. I build them directly to ~/Library/Frameworks so that everything I build automatically gets the latest versions.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (NSString*)usernameFromEmail:(NSString*)email
{
    NSString* username = nil;
    NSRange range = [email rangeOfString:@"@"];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        username = [email substringToIndex:range.location];
    }
    return username;
}
```